# Citadel 550 Invalid recipient

Tags: email-server, citadel

I tried to install citadel on a debian squeeze machine.

So far, what I've done is :

1. install citadel from the repo
2. create a user testuser & assign it the address testuser@mydomain.com
3. Add 2  mx record to cloudflare

   3a. mail.mydomain.com   1.2.3.4

   3b. MX : mydomain.com    mail.mydomain.com  40
4. edit my /etc/hosts file, and add myIP   mydomain.com\n myIP mail.mydomain.com

Then, I can send an email to my gmail account , and I can see in the recipient from : testuser@mydomain.com

However, when sending an email from my gmail account to testuser@mydomain.com, I've got this error message:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

   testuser@mydomain.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain     mydomain.com by mail.mydomain.com. [1.2.3.4].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 Invalid recipient: testusermydomain.com
```

Not that the '@' disapeared : testusermydomain.com instead of testuser@mydomain.com

When I try to send an email to testuser@mail.mydomain.com, I've got a different error message :

```
The error that the other server returned was:
551 <testuser@mail.mydomain.com> - relaying denied
```

I am relatively new to the mail server setup process, and I chosoe citadel for its simplicity. Does anyone got any idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: You might have run into a bug. Have you contacted citadel support on uncensored?

Comment: I haven't though about it. As this is a fresh debian install, and citadel being around for a long time... I will drop them a line on BBS uncensored and will update here.

Answer (score 1):

Following the intruction on this link made the setup work correctly.

http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2012/Jul/installing-citadel-on-rpi/

```
sudo mkdir /etc/citadel/netconfigs
sudo chown citadel:citadel /etc/citadel/netconfigs
sudo service citadel restart


sudo /usr/lib/citadel-server/setup
```

Then you will need to edit /etc/init.d/webcit, and put this just after #/bin/sh (If it is missing)

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:  webcit
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description: Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```